# How to deduct item in database using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

i need help to my inventory system that i'm doing right now,i have add,delete and search in it but i don't know how to deduct item in the database if someone buy's it. I'ts a POS and Inventory system guys please help me,i'm using MS access and for the connection i'm using oledb.

Comment: This is not enough information. Please post what you've tried, and what you actually want.

Comment: What i want to do is deduct an item inside the database.example i have 100 items in my database and the customer buy 1 then it will become 99. i don't know how to code that.sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are already established the connection with your Database using a "connection string", you need to query your specific datatable with an **SQL UPDATE Statement** command and change that value to by -1.

UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;

TO do this from VB you will use the **SqlClient.SqlCommand** to add your parameters and then execute you query.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the Search function, I believe  you're now able to get values from your database. So first, get the most recent value of your selected item from your database. Put the value on a variable , eg. item_recent_count = 100.
Then place also in a variable the value of the no. of items that was recently deducted, eg item_deducted_count=1.

then use this query as a basis:

```
Dim query as String= "UPDATE table_name SET item_count=" & item_recent_count - item_deducted_count & " WHERE item_name=selected_item"
```